# failed to clone nvm repo

Tags: windows, command-line, installation, npm

**I did**

- I tried to install nvm through `gitbash` also command prompt error has occurred.
  In the command prompt, asked me "`go to Microsoft store`" but I don't know what should I install.

**the command that I used**

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh |
```

**My environment**

- windows10 64 bit

**My goal**

- I want to update my npm to the new version(i did try `npm-windows-upgrade -p -v latest`...etc but all the things I have done was not work).also control node vsrsion.

Comment: Git Bash is not a suitable environment for NVM. // Upgrading npm is as easy as `npm install -g npm`.

Comment: @Daniel B That's did  not work but I did install nvm to my laptop and finally changed my node version to the latest

Comment: “Wi ndo0ws  Sub sys tem fo r L0inu x h as  no  ins0tal led” What the heck is that about?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 It’s `curl` output mixed with error output from invoking `bash` when WSL was enabled but no distributions installed. `bash` is a utility to invoke WSL.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Nvm from this link (`https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases`)
2. `nvm install <version>`
3. `nvm list`
4. `nvm use <vesion that you want to use>`